# OperationCanceledException when trying to authenticate user in AWS Cognito

Tags: c#, .net-core, amazon-cognito

I am playing around with AWS Cognito and I am trying to authenticate a user from my API backend.

But I am getting an "The operation was canceled." exception, and I don't know why!

Here is my code:

```
 var authReq = new AdminInitiateAuthRequest()
 {
     UserPoolId = this.UserpoolId,
     ClientId = this.ClientId,
     AuthFlow = AuthFlowType.ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH
 };
 authReq.AuthParameters.Add("USERNAME", username);
 authReq.AuthParameters.Add("PASSWORD", password);

 try
 {
     AdminInitiateAuthResponse authResp = await 
     this.SecClient.AdminInitiateAuthAsync(authReq);
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
     //The operation was canceled exception
 }
```

My Stack trace

> at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.HandleFinishSendAsyncError(Exception e,
>   CancellationTokenSource cts)\r\n    at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask,
>   HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean
>   disposeCts)\r\n    at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpClient.GetStringAsyncCore(Task`1 getTask)\r\n   at
>   Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.AsyncHelpers.<>c__DisplayClass1_1`1.<<RunSync>b__0>d.MoveNext()\r\n
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.AsyncHelpers.ExclusiveSynchronizationContext.BeginMessageLoop()
>   in
>   D:\\JenkinsWorkspaces\\trebuchet-stage-release\\AWSDotNetPublic\\sdk\\src\\Core\\Amazon.Runtime\\Internal\\Util\\_mobile\\AsyncHelpers.cs:line
>   142\r\n    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.AsyncHelpers.RunSync[T](Func`1 task) in
>   D:\JenkinsWorkspaces\trebuchet-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Internal\Util\_mobile\AsyncHelpers.cs:line
>   87\r\n   at Amazon.Util.AWSSDKUtils.DownloadStringContent(Uri uri,
>   TimeSpan timeout, IWebProxy proxy) in
>   D:\JenkinsWorkspaces\trebuchet-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Util\AWSSDKUtils.cs:line
>   1008\r\n   at Amazon.Util.EC2InstanceMetadata.GetItems(String
>   relativeOrAbsolutePath, Int32 tries, Boolean slurp) in
>   D:\JenkinsWorkspaces\trebuchet-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Util\_bcl+netstandard\EC2InstanceMetadata.cs:line
>   513\r\n   at
>   Amazon.Util.EC2InstanceMetadata.get_IAMSecurityCredentials() in
>   D:\JenkinsWorkspaces\trebuchet-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Util\_bcl+netstandard\EC2InstanceMetadata.cs:line
>   311\r\n   at
>   Amazon.Runtime.DefaultInstanceProfileAWSCredentials.FetchCredentials()
>   in
>   D:\JenkinsWorkspaces\trebuchet-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Credentials\_bcl+netstandard\DefaultInstanceProfileAWSCredentials.cs:line
>   142\r\n   at
>   Amazon.Runtime.DefaultInstanceProfileAWSCredentials.GetCredentials()
>   in
>   D:\JenkinsWorkspaces\trebuchet-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Credentials\_bcl+netstandard\DefaultInstanceProfileAWSCredentials.cs:line
>   88\r\n   at
>   Amazon.Runtime.DefaultInstanceProfileAWSCredentials.GetCredentialsAsync()
>   in
>   D:\JenkinsWorkspaces\trebuchet-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Credentials\_bcl+netstandard\DefaultInstanceProfileAWSCredentials.cs:line
>   106\r\n   at
>   Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CredentialsRetriever.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext
>   executionContext) in
>   D:\JenkinsWorkspaces\trebuchet-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\CredentialsRetriever.cs:line
>   90\r\n   at
>   Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext
>   executionContext)\r\n   at
>   Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext
>   executionContext) in
>   D:\JenkinsWorkspaces\trebuchet-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\RetryHandler\RetryHandler.cs:line
>   137\r\n   at
>   Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext
>   executionContext)\r\n   at
>   Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext
>   executionContext)\r\n   at
>   Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext
>   executionContext)\r\n   at
>   Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext
>   executionContext)\r\n   at
>   KaiserSmith.MS.Security.AWSCognitoAdapter.UserLogin(String username,
>   String password) in
>   C:\Users\Jason\Dropbox\Development\KaiserSmith.MS\BundleShared\Security\AWSCognitoAdapter.cs:line
>   83"   string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to resolve this myself.  I first started looking into network error, as point out by Vladimir in his answer.  I had already ruled out firewall problems on my local machine, so I tried from different machine several hours later and had the same issues.

I tried googling for similar issues, all with not luck.
But after much investigation I eventually found the cause, although the exception seems to be misleading.
During my google search I came across other examples which were initiating the client in a different manner, so I tried this and bingo!

So I changed this:

```
this.SecClient = new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUCentral1);
```

To become this

```
this.SecClient = new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(myAwsAccesskey, myAwsSecret,  Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUCentral1);
```

And this seems to have resolved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Let's traverse through stack trace & related source code:

> [System.Net.Http.HttpClient.HandleFinishSendAsyncError](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs#L557)
>   [System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs#L523)
>   ..
>   [System.Net.Http.HttpClient.GetStringAsyncCore(Task)](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs#L153)
>   ..
>   [SendAsync](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs#L435)
>   ..
>   [AWSSDKUtils.cs:line
>   1008](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/sdk/src/Core/Amazon.Util/AWSSDKUtils.cs#L999)
>   [Amazon.Util.EC2InstanceMetadata.GetItems](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/sdk/src/Core/Amazon.Util/_bcl+netstandard/EC2InstanceMetadata.cs#L517)
>   ..

The [OperationCanceledException](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs#L554) thrown when *cts (CancellationTokenSource)* is cancelled.
*cts* is cancelled when [HttpClient.Timeout expired or cancelled pending request](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs#L457).

HttpClient that initiated request [assigns the custom value](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/sdk/src/Core/Amazon.Util/AWSSDKUtils.cs#L1003) to [HttpClient.Timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout?view=netcore-2.2). Timeout is set to *5 seconds* in [Amazon.Util.EC2InstanceMetadata.GetItems](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/sdk/src/Core/Amazon.Util/_bcl+netstandard/EC2InstanceMetadata.cs#L517).

Conclusion: this request doesn't have time to execute for 5 second. Probably it is temporarily problem with AWS Cognito or some network latency issue.

Recommendations:

- if this fault is transient and may self-correct after a short delay then make sense to apply [Polly.RetryPolicy](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly#retry)
- try to research network latency.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the .NET Cognito Client was throwing either a OperationCancelledException or a SocketException (Host is down).

Because you did not provide any AWS Credentials to the constructor of the AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient it tried to send a HTTP request to http://169.254.169.254 to get the EC2 Instance Metadata (ultimately trying to get the EC2 Instance Profile or similar IAM Role that it should assume).

The solution is to provide invalid AWS credentials to the constructor.
new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(new Amazon.Runtime.BasicAWSCredentials(@"Invalid", @"Credentials"))

Socket Exception: Host is down was observed when 169.254.169.254 was routed out my ethernet interface and no ARP response could be obtained.